# Accessing props from object outside of React component

Tags: reactjs

In my React component, I use a third-party component that needs to be initialized. Up to this point, I handled this outside of the `class` -- see below but I now need to access some of the props inside this initialization and its current location is not working anymore.

Where's the proper place to handle this initialization? As I said, I now need to access the props inside this object so I'll have to move it. I tried placing it inside the `constructor` but it didn't work.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import ThirdPartyComponent from 'third-party-component'

const myInstance = new ThirdPartyComponent ({

   options: {
       someItem: "someValue",
       someOtherItem: this.props.something // Need to access props!
   }
});

class MyComponent extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
       super(props);
   };

   componentDidMount() {

      myInstance.on('complete', (x, y, z) => {

          // Do something
      })
   }

   render() {
      return(
         <div>
            <ThirdPartyComponent />
         </div>
      );
   };
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {

    return {
        something: state.module.something
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {

    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(someActions, dispatch)
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent )
```

Handling it inside `componentDidMount()` -- see below -- is giving me `myInstance` is not defined error.

```js
class MyComponent extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
       super(props);
   }

   componentDidMount() {

       const myInstance = new ThirdPartyComponent ({

          options: {
              someItem: "someValue",
              someOtherItem: this.props.something
          }
       });

       this.myInstance.on('complete', (x, y, z) => {

           // Do something
       });
   }

   render() {

       return(

           <div>Hello!</div>
       );
   }
}
```

Comment: Just instantiate it inside `componentDidMount`, and render that instance?

Comment: I tried it but got an error. Let me try again and tell you what the error is.

Comment: I'm getting `myInstance` undefined error

Comment: Yeah, you would have to check ofcourse that it is not null. I would have said componentWillMount before, but since this method will be deprecated, DidMount seems more appropriate. Theoretically, constructor is also fine, as props is one of the arguments given into the constructor (and then you probably don't have to check for null in the rendering). Also, you seem to create `myInstance` but you are rendering `ThirdPartyComponent`

Comment: I'm not quite following your suggestion yet. I updated the original post to show you how I handled it inside `componentDidMount()`. The problem is that it keeps telling me that `myInstance is not defined`

Comment: right, but you are declaring a local variable `const myInstance`, and not assigning the property `myInstance` on the `this` object :) Which I guess might as well be a copy paste error

Comment: I tried `this.myInstance = this.myInstance.bind(this);` both inside `constructor` and `componentDidMount()` and still getting not defined error. Would you mind posting your suggestion as code so that I can see what you mean?

Comment: Look, I just ment you should do it rather like this: http://jsfiddle.net/oraej8g5/

Comment: Got it!!!! Thank you! I'll upvote your comment but if you post your code as answer, I'll accept it so that you can credit for your help. Thanks again!